# MySQL: group comments by threads, sorted by score and post date

Tags: mysql

I'm building a MySQL db for user comments, posted about specific topics.

- each topic has many comments
- there are two types of comments: roots and replies
- all replies to the same root, along with that root, belong to the same thread
- The `ThreadID` equals the `CommentID` of the root

Here is sample data:
[image]

I'm trying to build a MySQL query that will select all comments for topic #55, arranged thus:

- comments from the same `ThreadID` should be listed together
- order by highest-scoring thread first (thread score is sum of comments scores)
- if thread scores are equal, the thread with the oldest root comment is first
- within a thread, order by oldest comment first

The result should also have a column with `ThreadScore`

The solution would look like:
[image]

Unfortunately I've been unable to get things working in one efficient query.

My current query groups by thread correctly, but doesn't account for scores:

```
select * from comments c
where c.Topic=55
order by c.ThreadID asc, c.TimeCreated asc
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39bb14/1) where you can test queries against this table

Comment: @e4c5 if you click the link at the bottom of my post to go to the fiddle, you will see the data as text on the left side of the page. Does that work?

Comment: oops sorry missed that part. Robo commented after seeing all the tables as screenshots!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query

```
select c.*, ct.ThreadScore from comments c
join (select ThreadId, sum(Score) ThreadScore
     from comments
     group by ThreadId) ct
     on c.ThreadId = ct.ThreadId
where c.Topic=55
order by c.ThreadId asc, ct.ThreadScore desc, c.TimeCreated asc
```

The result I got is

[image]

Hope this should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Viki. One concern: if two threads have the same score, wouldn't your `Order by` clause mix up posts from different threads based on `TimeCreated`? The desired behavior in that case is for the thread with the oldest root comment to be listed first.

Comment: Yes If you notice in `Order by` Timecreated is ordered in asc `TimeCreated asc`. Which means if `ThreadScore` is same for two rows, then it will be order by oldest `TimeCreated`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your solution breaks my first requirement. If two threads have the same `ThreadScore`, the thread with the oldest post should have all its comments listed first. With your query, the comments from multiple threads become mixed up if `ThreadScore` is the same. Take a [look at this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6dbf8/2) and notice how there is a comment from `ThreadID 7` in the middle of `ThreadID 1`

Comment: I cannot select it as the answer because it doesn't work as is, but I upvote because you got me most of the way there.

Comment: My only question is, does your sample data has the scenario which you are facing?

Comment: I'm replying based on the result from the sample data on the linked fiddles. If you run your query as it is right now, you'll notice that it doesn't meet all the reqs. That's the only reason I have not chosen it. My real table is not populated yet; I'm at the design stage. Your answer has been helpful